# Filezilla server with outside client

Tags: server, client, filezilla

I'm using Filezilla server as my SFTP. My question is, does Filezilla server only connect with the Filezilla client, or can it communicate with any SFTP client?

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

FileZilla Server is a server that supports FTP and FTP over TLS which provides secure encrypted connections to the server. (from https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/FileZilla_FTP_Server). Support for SFTP (SSH File Transfer Protocol) is not implemented in Filezilla Server.

So you can serve any client that talks FTP or FTPS, but not SFTP

Comment: please Mark as Answer if you're satisfied